# openssl_public_encrypt() in Flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to use something similar to this php function
`openssl_public_encrypt('text', $output, $publicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);`
in Flutter (Dart). What is the easiest way to accomplish that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) library.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

final plainText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';
final publicKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(File('public.pem').readAsStringSync());
final privateKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(File('private.pem').readAsStringSync());

final encrypter = Encrypter(
  RSA(
    publicKey: publicKey,
    privateKey: privateKey,
    encoding: RSAEncoding.PKCS1,
  ),
);

final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText);
final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt64(encrypted.base64);
```