# PHP and Dart two-way encryption

Tags: php, encryption, dart, two-way

I'm looking for a secure library in PHP and Dart so I can send encrypted data from Dart and decrypt it in PHP. I have no knowledge in Dart so I need help please.i Searched and found some encryption libraries but nothing is common yet between Dart and PHP.

Comment: Why not use HTTPS to establish a secure communication line between you running Dart code and PHP? It seems rather unnecessary to begin implementing manual encryption.

Comment: HTTPS will be established but may get cracked and data will be insecure

Comment: On what basis do you think HTTPS will get cracked?

Comment: Many hackers could crack or hack the encrypted data (the SSL encryption) and extract plain data as I read on the internet SSL is not 100% safe and pain data should also be encrypted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you can use [openssl_public_encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) and [openssl_private_decrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php), in Dart you can use [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) library. Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58243570/9925520).